# Add items from ObjectCollection to an IList(Of SomeType)

Tags: .net, vb.net, collections, object, ilist

How could I add ObjectCollection items to an IList(Of SomeType)?
I have tried with:

```
For Each obj As SomeType In listBox.Items 'ObjectCollection
    MyObject.ItProperty.Add(obj) 'IList
Next
```

No success.
Thank you.

Comment: I think you're missing some text. It ends with "I have tried with:".

Comment: I've change that. Sorry and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, the non-generic `IList` interface would be the simplest approach:

```
IList list = (IList)MyObject.ItProperty;
list.Add(obj);
```

Otherwise, you will have to:

- find the appropriate `T` (using reflection)
- resolve the `Add` method from `IList<T>` (using reflection)
- invoke the `Add` method (using reflection)

that reflection, *especially* on generics, is not nice.

As an alternative - if you have 4.0 you could try using `dynamic`, but note this only sees the public API. Worth a try though (only if `IList` fails):

```
dynamic list = MyObject.ItProperty;
list.Add(obj); // let's hope Add isn't an explicit interface implementation
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add some details about what fails and where? Your code should work.

If you are getting an exception `"Unable to cast object of type 'XXX' to type 'SomeType'."` at the "`For Each obj` " line, then there is at least an item in the listBox.Items collection that is not of type 'SomeType'.